# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_html' Twetter

Tags: python, pip

Currently I am working Covid-19 sentimental analysis where I am using twitter_scraper for scraping my data.
After run following line of code I get an error.

```
from twitter_scraper import get_tweets
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_html'

I install  'requests_html' by running command:

```
pip3 install requests-html
```

I also get some error after this command in prompt command

```
Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main

  status = self.run(options, args)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 360, in run

  prefix=options.prefix_path,

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install

  **kwargs

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install

  self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files

  isolated=self.isolated,

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 247, in move_wheel_files  

prefix=prefix,

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 153, in distutils_scheme

  i.finalize_options()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 351, in finalize_options

  self.create_home_path()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 581, in create_home_path

  os.makedirs(path, 0o700)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs

  makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs

  mkdir(name, mode)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/subhash/.local/lib/python3.6'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please don't spam tags, this isn't related to machine-learning and the wiki for sensitive-data says "Please don't use this tag". Removed both of these.

Comment: sentimental analysis is a part of machine learning. If you have a solution please tell.

Comment: But your problem posted above is about pip installation, it's not related to sentiment analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip defaults to installing Python packages to a system directory which requires root access.

Do you have root permissions? If so, please try to run `sudo pip install...`.
Otherwise, consider installing the dependency to your home directory instead which doesn't require any special privileges:

```
pip install --user requests-html
```

Comment: with sudo....it give.....The directory '/home/subhash/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/subhash/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Comment: raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/request-html/

Comment: It works. Thanks. I am using pip3 for this but it works for pip.